# Util method to create map from collection

Tags: java, generics, methods, lambda, static-methods

I try to create static method that creates map of instance field as key and instance itself as value. I tried something like this:

```
public static <T> Map<Object, T> collectionToMap(Collection<T> collection, Function<Object, T> fieldExtractor) {
        return collection.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(fieldExtractor, e -> e));
    }
```

But when I tried pass a function as an argument. I have compilation error, because `getEmail()` method non static, but `toMap()` static.

```
ProjectUtils.collectionToMap(collection, User::getEmail);
```

How can I write static method with similar signature and pass non static method reference? Or maybe another approach exists to do this?

Comment: Assuming `collection` is a `Collection<User>`, I think you just need to use `Function<T,Object>` instead of `Function<Object,T>` for the key extractor. I don't see what this has to do with static and non-static. What is the actual text of the compilation error you are getting?

Comment: Oh it's actually works! Thanks. The error was: invalid method reference non-static method getEmail() cannot be referenced from a static context. The error is really confusing.

Comment: Personally I'd opt for not using `Object` as the key type. `public static <T, R> Map<R, T> collectionToMap(Collection<T> collection, Function<T, R> fieldExtractor)`

Comment: @Radiodef, If try to compile I had to errors actually. The second one point to real reason that you describe. But IDE said just about non static.

Comment: d.j.brown, fully agree, thanks

Comment: Also worth noting that this will fall over on duplicate keys. Assuming other business rules prevent this being the case you’re fine, otherwise you need to specify a merger.

Comment: @d.j.brown, yes business rules prevent this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a generic method `collectionToMap` like so.

```
public static <T, S> Map<S, T> collectionToMap(Collection<? extends T> collection,
    Function<? super T, ? extends S> fieldExtractor) {
    return collection.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(fieldExtractor, v -> v, (a, b) -> a));
}
```

Then the client code should be something like this.

```
ProjectUtils.collectionToMap(Collections.emptyList(), User::getEmail);
```